# How to check if txt file exists inside template folder?

Tags: include, filesystem, wp-filesystem, template-include

I have a folder inside my theme where I hold some txt files which I am including in a theme. The problem is that before including txt file I need to check if it does exist. I fail checking it the following way and have no idea why it wont work, always returns false.

```
$themeLocation = get_bloginfo('template_url');
$fileName1 = $themeLocation.'/txtfolder/file1.txt';

if(is_file($fileName1)){
   echo 'It does exist';
} else {
   echo 'Error';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to check it by URL, which makes no sense to `is_file()` which expects local path. By the way I'd use `file_exists()` instead.

Try:

```
$fileName1 = TEMPLATEPATH . '/txtfolder/file1.txt';
```

Comment: @Rarst Is there any particular reason why you'd use `file_exists()` over `is_file()` in this case?

Comment: @w3d not really, just more used to see `file_exists()` check used (or at least used first). Hadn't really looked into nuances.